# I this code getAllProductDetails should call first,but the adapter is running first and then only service calling is happening

Tags: android

I have this code `getAllProductDetails(code)` method should call first, but the adapter is running first and then only service calling is happening.

I am getting `images` list size as `0`. Where does the problem lie?

```java
   code = 500;

    getAllProductDetails(code);

    displayProduct();
    getReviews(productDetails.getPCode());

    /*Horizontal Images Recycler view*/
    horizontalRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_recycler);

    horizontalRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    horizontalRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    horizontalImagesAdapter = new HorizontalImagesAdapter(this, images, Glide.with(this), new HorizontalImagesAdapter.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {

            imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(images.get(position).getImageUrl()));
            imagePos = Integer.toString(position);
        }
    });
    horizontalRecycler.setAdapter(horizontalImagesAdapter);
}

private void getAllProductDetails(int code){

    getRetrofitInterface().getSingleProductDetails(code).enqueue(new Callback<List<ProductDetails>>() {
        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ProductDetails>> call, Response<List<ProductDetails>> response) {
            try {

                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    List<ProductDetails> productDetailslist = response.body();
                    if (productDetailslist != null && productDetailslist.size() > 0) {
                        Log.i("PRODUCTS_LIST RESPONSE ------------>", productDetailslist.get(0).getResponseMsg());
                        ProductDetails productDetails = productDetailslist.get(0);
                        txtTitle.setText(productDetails.getpName());
                        txtPrice.setText("Rs." + productDetails.getProductPriceBeforeDiscount());
                        images.add(new Images(productDetails.getpImage1()));
                        images.add(new Images(productDetails.getpImage2()));
                        images.add(new Images(productDetails.getpImage3()));
                        images.add(new Images(productDetails.getpImage4()));

                        imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(productDetails.getpImage1()));                       
                        GlideImageLoader.loadImage(ProductDetailActivity.this, glide, imageView, 
                        productDetails.getpImage1());
                    }
                    else {
                        showUnknownError(null);
                    }
                } else {
                    String message = "";
                    int code;
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
                        message = jsonObject.getString("ResponseMsg");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    code = response.raw().code();
                    showError(code, null, message);
                }

            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<ProductDetails>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you checked the API in postman is it giving image size >0?ifs a case after your response set your adapter

Comment: after getAllProductDetails() call, put everthing in the response of that call. I mean setAdapter everthing

Answer (score 0):

Your should call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `HorizontalImagesAdapter` after you changed the list

It's better to store the list in an adapter. And provide a method like `void setItems(List<Items>)` for encapsulation

Answer (score 0):

getAllProductDetails is making an asynchronous request.  Then the adapter gets set with an empty images list.  Then the request finishes.  You need to set your adapter inside onResponse.  That way you have a non empty list

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter is getting populated before your API call can finish which is why the adapter is empty. Instead attach the adapter to an empty list initially and in the success part of your API call, set the adapter to the data.